# RTD Temperature Reading

Tags: pic, pt100

I developed a circuit to read a temperature value [30,60] with a PT100 using a PIC32.The circuit has a 1mA current source connected to the PT100.The PT100 is then connected to a differential op amp to accommodate de voltage to the 3.3V Range of the ADC.The other input is the value of V in the PT100 for my minimum temperature (30Degrees)(Since V=RI I calculated the PT100 Resistance at 30º with the Callendar-van Dusen Eq and multiplied it by 1mA).So I Have Vo=(Gain*(PT-PTmin)).
The question is now that my output is [0,3.3]V can I calculate the temperature in the PIC by just linearizing the ADC value (something like 1023-60 and 0-30) or do I still need to calculate the Resistance in the PT100 and from that get the temperature?Im trying to get at least a 1º accuracy in the readings if that makes a difference.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick check, you can assume that if you scale the reading such that 30°C and 60°C are exact, the maximum error will occur near 45°C. So you can calculate that error and see if it is close enough for your purposes.

Using the DIN curve \$\alpha=0.00385\$, 30°C is 111.67\$\Omega\$ and 60°C is 123.24\$\Omega\$ so mid-scale is 117.455\$\Omega\$.

The actual resistance for 45°C is 117.47\$\Omega\$, for a difference of 0.015\$\Omega\$ or about 0.04°C, or roughly doubling the error of a 1/10 DIN sensor.

Comment: Thank you Spehro!.I checked it and yes at half the range I get about 0.04ºC of error.Since im trying to measure the temps in 1º Steps this shouldn't be a major problem right?

Comment: Should be fine over such a narrow range. There's an analog trick you can do with the current source to make it even better but I don't think it's worth it.